Interpreting SMART failure for Crucial MTFDDAV512TBN SSD
I bought a secondhand SSD (I know, I know).  Trying to decide whether to return it now.  It shows as failing in smartctl and also in Crucial's "Storage Executive" software.  My hesitation is that I believe SMART attributes aren't always consistent/interpreted correctly by all software, especially for SSDs.  Here's the output of smartctl -a:
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron Client SSDs
Device Model:     MTFDDAV512TBN-1AR1ZABHA
Serial Number:    UFZND01J189ZK0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1184eff8a
Firmware Version: HPC0012
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 27 11:59:54 2024 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

...
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 32
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   050    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 1792
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0033   090   090   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       231
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4806
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3966
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   097   097   005    Old_age   Always       -       65
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       195
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0022   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       2062
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23557981737035
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x003b   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       387
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3971
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   061   034   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 13/66)
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2047348 (0 0 54)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28991370509
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       49646510651
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1318919006

Would you keep it?!

No, I would trust the S.M.A.R.T data. Those attributes are perfectly consistent
